# 入力値にひらがな・カタカナ・漢字以外が含まれていないかを調べたい

Tags: javascript, 正規表現

キーボードで入力できる全角記号を除外したいのですが、知識不足で理解できず、どなたかご教授いただければと存じます。

■やりたい事■
 フォームの名前フィールド（全角漢字）で、登録許可項目以外エラーメッセージを表示
 エラーは送信ボタンを選択する前に表示したい。その為JSでバリデーションを作成している
 ※ブラックリストを作成し、Ajaxで確認する方法もあるかと思いますが、一旦は正規表現での
　 やり方をご教授いただければと存じます。

▲フィールドの登録許可▲
 漢字・全角カナ

●現在設定したバリデーション●
 半角記号・連続文字

■現在作成した正規表現■

```
/^([\w\u3040-\u309f])\1*$|\d+|[a-zA-Z]|[!-/]|[:-?]|[[-`]|[{-~]/
```

▲止まっている所▲
キーボードで入力できる全角記号除外の正規表現

元々の要望は漢字　カナ　ひらがな 　以外は登録を除外するという要望なので、
カナ　ひらがな 　以外は登録を除外という正規表現の書き方がありましたら、その内容もご教授いただければと存じます。　恐れ入りますが、よろしくお願いします

Comment: かな漢字に制限したいのかなという気もするのですが、「キーボードで入力できる」という縛りですと、ソフトウェアキーボード/文字パレット的なものからなんとか入力できる文字の扱いはどうなるのでしょう。

Comment: @sakuro様
かな漢字に制限したいのかなという気もするのですが    
⇛はい　仰るとおりです。　元々の要望は　漢字　カナ　ひらがな    
　以外は登録を除外するという要望です。　ただ、その正規表現の    
    書き方が不明だったため　上記要望にしました。  　
　漢字　カナ　ひらがな以外は登録を除外するという書き方が  
　ありましたらご教授いただければと存じます  

　ソフトウェアキーボード/文‌​字パレット的なものからなんとか入力できる‌​文字の扱いはどうなるのでしょう  
⇛一旦は正規表現の対象から除外　つまりパレット等では入力できる状態で問題ございません

Comment: Unicode プロパティが使えるのであれば、この記事 [ユニコード文字プロパティについて](http://js-next.hatenablog.com/entry/2016/04/21/013010) が参考になるかと思います。

Comment: metropolis様　ありがとうございます　確認させていただきます

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ご教授頂いたユニコード文字プロパティが利用できなかったので、べた書きで対応しました。
もっとよい書き方があるかもしれませんが、、、、

```
/^([\w\u3040-\u309f])\1*$|\d+|[a-zA-Z]|[!-/]|[:-?]|[[-`]|[{-~]|["！”＃＄％＆’（）＝～｜‘｛＋＊｝＜＞？＿－＾￥＠「；：」、。・"]/
```